# Styling multiple items CSS one tag

Tags: html, css, tags

I have a table with a bunch of items, say 20. Every other row has a specific background color and the items in the cell do as well.

I achieve this with the following piece of CSS:

```
#item_list tr:nth-child(even), 
#item_list tr:nth-child(even) input[type="text"], 
#item_list tr:nth-child(even) input[type="number"] {
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

My question is whether there is a neater way to end up with the same styling? Specifically without the repetition of

```
#item_list tr:nth-child(even)
```

or not?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Comment: you could give each item an individual class name. But that's not really more nice and you need to alter the dom. You could be interessting in using SCSS or another CSS precompiler to be able to write things like: `#item_list tr:nth-child(even){ input[type="text"] { ... } }`. But that will not change the output in the resulting .css file.

Comment: How many repetitions of `#item_list tr:nth-child(even)` is too many? You can try marking the `input` elements with a CSS class, then end up with two selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Not using CSS.

If you use a pre-processor such as SASS or LESS then you could get syntax like:

```
#item_list tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d4d4d4;

    input[type="text"],   
    input[type="number"] {
        background-color: #d4d4d4;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not used SCSS before but looks like you need a more `background-color:#d4d4d4;` outside (right in the outer `{}`)?